# laravel-remove duplicates from drop down menu

Tags: laravel

I have a drop down menu that lists the information from my database. I have 4 entries in my menu and i have purposely named two posts the same to see if it returns both posts. However, it is showing twice in my drop down menu. How do i ensure that only one value is showing, BUT returns both posts.

> Search.blade.php

```
@extends ('layouts.app')
@section('content')  

 {!! Form::open(['action' => 'SearchController@index', 'method' => 'GET']) !!}
 <div class="form-group">
<select name="distance" id="distance" class="form-control input-lg dynamic" data-dependent="state">
    <option value="">Choose an item</option>
    @foreach($posts as $post)
        <option value="{{ $post->id }}">{{ $post->distance }}</option>
    @endforeach
   </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::Submit('submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}
  </div>
  @if($request)

            <p>{{ $request->title }}</p>
            <p>{{ $request->distance }}</p>
            <img src="{{$request->image}}" height = 200 width =200>

@endif
```

> SearchController.php

```
 public function index(Request $request)
 {
   $posts = Post::all();

   $selectedPost = $request->has('distance')
       ? Post::find($request->distance)
       : null;

   return view('Pages.search', [
       'posts' => $posts,
       'request' => $selectedPost
   ]);
```

}

```
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
   // This will return all request data to your screen.
   return $request->all();
   return view('Pages.search');
   }
```

Comment: Did you have time to look at my answer or are you facing other issues? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two approaches using the database or doing it in context of Laravel collections.

**Sql approach**

Use the dinstinct keyword, to select only unique posts.

```
 $posts = Post::distinct('title')->all();
```

**Laravel collection approach**

Use the unique collection method on your posts.

```
 $posts = Post::all();

 $uniquePosts = $posts->unique('title');
```

The `SQL` approach is more optimal, but sometimes it is just easy to utilize the Laravel collections methods.